# regrading adding a legend using ggplot2 for different lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to add a legend that will tell which color represents which line using `ggplot2`.
My code is as follows :

```
require(lme4)
require(ggplot2)
m1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1+I(Days) + (1+ Days| Subject) , data = sleepstudy)

pred1new1=predict(m1,re.form=NA)
```

To add a legend, i tried `scale_colour_manual` , but it didnt worked.

```
p21 <- ggplot(data = sleepstudy, aes(x = Days, y = Reaction))
p21+ geom_point() + geom_smooth(col="blue")+ geom_line(aes(y=pred1new1,group = Subject) ,col="red", lwd = 0.5)+
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'the colour', 
                      values =c('blue'='blue','red'='red'), labels = c('smooth','pred'))
```

[image]

Can anyone suggest anything to fix this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the color parameter in `aes` and give it the name you want to show in the the legend and then choose the title and colors in `scale_color_manual`

Example:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(color='Smooth 1')) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = (hwy -1), color='Smooth 2')) +
  scale_color_manual('Legend Title', values=c('Smooth 1'='blue', 'Smooth 2'='red'))
```