# How to add a legend to multiple plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have this code:

```
testPlot= ggplot(residFrame) +
  geom_point(aes(x=STATEFP, y=total_diff, colour='total'), colour='red', shape=1) +
  geom_point(aes(x=STATEFP, y=desalination_diff, colour='desalination'), colour='blue', shape=1) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=STATEFP, y=surfacewater_diff), colour='green', shape=1) +
  geom_point(aes(x=STATEFP, y=groundwater_diff), colour='yellow', shape=1) +
  xlab('STATEFP') + ylab('Difference') + ggtitle('Difference for all states', subtitle='For each source')
testPlot
```

And now I want to add a legend to testPlot that describes what the colours in the plot represent. I have searched the web, but cannot find the answer to this particular problem, can someone help me out here?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regrading adding a legend using ggplot2 for different lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61730874/regrading-adding-a-legend-using-ggplot2-for-different-lines)

Answer (score 0):

You should get the data in long format and then plot instead of calling `geom_point` multiple times. You have not provided an example of your data but you can try.

```
library(ggplot2)

residFrame %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = ends_with('diff')) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(STATEFP, value, color = name) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1) + 
  xlab('STATEFP') + ylab('Difference') + 
  ggtitle('Difference for all states', subtitle='For each source')
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect! Is there also a way to change the title of the legend?

Comment: You can have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622421/how-to-change-legend-title-in-ggplot